# Integration over angles (volume element change)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics

I'm trying to change from one volume element to another, as suggested in a problem 13.2 of Reif's Statistical and Thermal Physics. My volume element is currently:

$d^3$$\nu$

And I'd like to change it into spherical coordinates so I can integrate over angles. My new proposed volume elements are:

$dV$ = $d\nu d\theta d\phi$

So that I can integrate from 0 to infinity in $\nu$, 0 to $\pi$ in $\theta$ and 0 to $2\pi$ in $\phi$.

How can this be done with the Jacobian matrix?

Thanks.

Comment: Please give more detail about the problem you're talking about. What do you mean "change it into spherical coordinates in terms of spherical coordinates"? I also don't know what $\frac{1}{3}$ factor you're talking about.

Comment: I had changed my question and did not edit the text after it. Maybe this is more clear.

Comment: Are you just asking what the Jacobian is?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you actually meant problem 13.1.

Notice that, since the integration limits for $v_x$, $v_y$ and $v_z$ are the same, and since $d^3v=dv_x\,dv_y\,dv_z$, the value of the integral (call it $I$) is the same if you have $v_x^2$ or $v_y^2$ in place of $v_z^2$. This means that integrating with $v^2$ (which is equal to $v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2$) in place of $v_z^2$ gives $I'=3I$, hence $I=I'/3$.

Finally, in "$v$-space", you change the "volume" element from cartesian
$$d\mathcal{V}=d^3v=dv_x\,dv_y\,dv_z$$ 
to spherical coordinates
$$d\mathcal{V}=d^3v=v^2\sin{\theta}\,dv\,d\theta\,d\phi$$
For details on how to use the jacobian to get this result, check pages 7-8 of [this document](http://booksite.elsevier.com/andrilli/elementary/content/jacobian.pdf), taking into account the rightful correspondences, e.g., $x\leftrightarrow v_x$, $y\leftrightarrow v_y$, $z\leftrightarrow v_z$, $\rho\leftrightarrow v$ etc.